# Not unique table alias in datatables Laravel

Tags: php, database, laravel, eloquent

Im using Eloquent eager load to show all the childrens of an animal in a Yajra datatable, but Im getting this error:

[image]

My function where I get all the childrens:

```
public function hijos()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Ganado', 'hijos_padres', 'id_padre', 'id_hijo');
}
```

My datatable code:

```
    if ($request->ajax()) {

        return datatables()
            ->eloquent(Ganado::where('id_ganado', $id)->with('hijos'))    

            ->toJson();
    }
```

and this:

```
{data: 'hijos.id_ganado', name: 'hijos.id_ganado'},
{data: 'hijos.codigo_ganado', name: 'hijos.codigo_ganado'},
{data: 'hijos.genero', name: 'hijos.genero'},
```

My "hijos" (childrens) function have an itself relationship so I dont know how I can give an alias to the table.

This is my Animal table:

[image]

What else I can do?

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is that the model is self referencing.

Solution: You should alias the table in the join.

Something like this:

```
Ganado::select('ganado.*')->leftJoin('ganado AS myAlias', 'ganado.mycolumn', '=', 'myAlias.other_column');
```